# show excerpt of database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking for a Cypher query that will show an excerpt of the data in a Neo4j database. I need this to provide a quick overview of what kind of data can be found in the db.

The query should show a certain number of nodes for all labels with all possible relations between them. Basically I want to get a subset of the nodes in the database which contains the full complexity of the data in the database.

I tried to accomplish this with LIMIT but this only limits the total number of nodes returned.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [set of procedures](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#meta-graph) for this via the APOC library(Neo4j 3x): apoc.meta.graph

e.g. `CALL apoc.meta.graph` will iterate over the graph and collect labels and relationships it finds.

There's a writeup of the meta procedures in this [blog post](https://neo4j.com/blog/intro-user-defined-procedures-apoc/).